# Google Analytics (GA4) add_to_cart/remove_from_cart quantity dimension meaning is unclear. Total quantity after the event or delta of the quantity?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

After scouring docs I am unable to find the answer to this.

Is the "quantity" dimension for add_to_cart/remove_from_cart GA4 eCommerce events meant to represent the delta quantity of the product for this particular event, or the total quantity of the underlying item after the event processes?

For example let us say the following occurs:

- User has 4 of item A in cart.
- User changes the quantity of item A to 1 in the cart.
- Emit remove_from_cart event.

On this remove_from_cart event is the quantity 3 (because 3 were removed from the cart) or 1? (because the quantity after processing the event is 1)

Comment: It’s the quantity that you add or remove.

Answer (score 0):

I have since learned that this quantity is meant to be the quantity in the cart after the adjustment is made, not the delta of the quantity before and after the event.